# When p ranges from 0 to infinity, S is obtained by numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

The parameters and functions are loaded as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
epslon = 8.9;
Z = 1.0/epslon; l = 1.0; R0 = 2;
EE = 2.419601;
β0 = Sqrt[-Z^2/(2*EE)];
Rnl[r_] := Hypergeometric1F1[l + 1 - β0, 2 l + 2, (2 Z r)/β0] Exp[(-2 Z r)/(2 β0)] ( (2 Z r)/β0)^l;
Rnlh[p_?NumericQ] := -Sqrt[(2/Pi)] NIntegrate[r^2 Rnl[r] (Sin[p r]/(p r)^2 - Cos[p r]/(p r)), {r, 0, R0}];
normp = Norm[Sqrt[NIntegrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]]];
Rnlend[p_?NumericQ] := Rnlh[p]/normp;
fp[p_?NumericQ, θp_?NumericQ] := (3 Cos[θp]^2)/(4 π) Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2;
```

What I want to calculate is: $S=-2\pi \int_0^{\infty}{\int_0^{\pi}{fp\cdot \ln \left( fp \right) \cdot p^2}}\sin \theta dpd\theta$

Because the range of `p` is `0 to infinity` when calculating `S`, no result can be obtained after the calculation for a long time. I give the range of `p` as `0-10` for preliminary test.

**Method 1：**

```
S1 = -2 Pi  NIntegrate[fp[p, θ] Log[fp[p, θ]] p^2 Sin[θ], {p, 0, 10}, {θ, 0, Pi}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1155.65, 4.42307}

**Method 2：**
the idea of changing variables

$$
fp=\frac{3}{4\pi}\cos ^2\theta \cdot \left| \text{R}nlend \right|^2
$$
$$
S=-2\pi \int_0^{\infty}{\int_0^{\pi}{fp\cdot \ln \left( fp \right) \cdot p^2}}\sin \theta dpd\theta 
$$
$$
Let\ \cos \theta =y
$$
$$
S2=S=-2\pi \int_0^{\infty}{\int_{-1}^1{\frac{3y^2}{4\pi}}}\left| Rnlend \right|^2\ln \left( \frac{3}{4\pi}y^2\left| Rnlend \right|^2 \right) p^2dpdy
$$

```
S2 = -2 Pi  NIntegrate[(3 y^2)/(4 Pi)
      Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2 Log[3/(4 Pi) y^2 Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2] p^2, {p, 
     0, 10}, {y, -1, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {234.691, 4.42307}

To sum up, we can find that the speed of **Method 2** is much faster than that of **Method 1**, but it is still unable to solve the solution when the `p` range is `0 to infinity`. So ask if there is a better solution.

Comment: `normp` is complex?

Comment: The actual normalization coefficient `normp` should be real. I've added `Norm` to `fp`. `normp` can also be `Norm` in advance.

Comment: But `normp` is still used inside `Rlend[]`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code.

Comment: Do you have more information about your parameters `epslon`, `Z`, `l`, `R0`, `EE`? What values can they take on? There may be some preprocessing / simplifying that can be done in order to significantly accelerate the computation(s).

Comment: These parameters cannot be changed for my application at present. I mainly want to deal with integration techniques and other aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to reduce the double integral to a single integral:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
    fp=\frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi}\left| Rnlend \right|^2\\
    S=-2\pi \int_0^{\infty}{\int_0^{\pi}{fp\cdot \ln \left( fp \right) p^2\sin \theta dpd}}\theta\\
    =\int_0^{\infty}{\int_0^{\pi}{\frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi}\left| Rnlend \right|^2\cdot \left( \ln \left( \frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi} \right) +\ln \left( \left| Rnlend \right|^2 \right) \right) p^2\sin \theta dpd}}\theta\\
    =\int_0^{\infty}{\int_0^{\pi}{\frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi}\left| Rnlend \right|^2\ln \left( \frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi} \right) p^2\sin \theta dpd}}\theta +\int_0^{\infty}{\int_0^{\pi}{\frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi}\left| Rnlend \right|^2\ln \left( \left| Rnlend \right|^2 \right) p^2\sin \theta dpd}}\theta\\
\end{array}
$$

Let:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
    C_1=\int_0^{\pi}{\frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi}\ln \left( \frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi} \right) \sin \theta}d\theta\\
    C_2=\int_0^{\pi}{\frac{3\cos ^2\theta}{4\pi}\sin \theta}d\theta\\
\end{array}
$$

So the final simplification result is as follows:
$$
S=-2\pi \left( C_1\int_0^{\infty}{\left| Rnlend \right|^2p^2dp}+C_2\int_0^{\infty}{\left| Rnlend \right|^2\ln \left( \left| Rnlend \right|^2 \right) p^2dp} \right) 
$$

Comparing the above two methods, when p ranges from 0 to 10:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
epslon = 8.9;
Z = 1.0/epslon; l = 1.0; R0 = 2;
EE = 2.419601;
\[Beta]0 = Sqrt[-Z^2/(2*EE)];
Rnl[r_] := 
  Hypergeometric1F1[l + 1 - \[Beta]0, 
    2 l + 2, (2 Z r)/\[Beta]0] Exp[(-2 Z r)/(2 \[Beta]0)] ((2 Z r)/\
\[Beta]0)^l;
Rnlh[p_?NumericQ] := -Sqrt[(2/Pi)] NIntegrate[
    r^2 Rnl[r] (Sin[p r]/(p r)^2 - Cos[p r]/(p r)), {r, 0, R0}];
normp = Norm[Sqrt[NIntegrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]]];
Rnlend[p_?NumericQ] := Rnlh[p]/normp;
C1 = NIntegrate[(3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(4 Pi)
     Log[(3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(4 Pi)] Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}];
C2 = NIntegrate[(3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(4 Pi) Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 
    0, Pi}];
S = -2 Pi (C1 NIntegrate[Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2 p^2, {p, 0, 10}] + 
     C2 NIntegrate[
       Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2 Log[Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2] p^2, {p, 0, 10}]) // 
  AbsoluteTiming
```

The result:

> {47.8886, 4.42307}

When p ranges from 0 to infinity:

```
S = -2 Pi (C1 NIntegrate[Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2 p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}] + 
     C2 NIntegrate[
       Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2 Log[Norm[Rnlend[p]]^2] p^2, {p, 0, 
        Infinity}]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

The result:

> {780.926, 4.43211}

This method is optimized to meet my needs in terms of computational efficiency and accuracy.